# Why only ten? Why not all of Haman's children?

Tags: megillat-esther, family-members, capital-punishment, tractate-megillah, haman

According to the Gemara [Megila 15b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah_15b.19) Haman had 208 children. Why did they only hang 10 of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These were the ones who had instigated the decree by which Achashveirosh halted the building of Beis Hamikdosh soon after he ascended to the throne. Megilah 16a - Rashi quoting Seder Olam.

Comment: Can you clarify your source? I think the Gemara/Rashi you're referring to is talking about Shimshi, Achashverosh's scribe.

Comment: Me'am Loez says the same thing, and gives as source references: Rashi, Maamar Mordechai, and Megillas Sesarim.

Comment: http://dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=megilah&daf=16a&go=Go
What am I missing??

Comment: Shimshai was the son of Homon (Rashi Ezra 4:8) Maharsha Megilah 16a

Comment: also, look in the hagois habach on the first Rashi on 16a

Answer (score 1):

The Ben Yehoyada to that Gemara [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Yehoyada_on_Megillah.15b.18?lang=bi):

> עֲשָׂרָה מֵתוּ, וַעֲשָׂרָה נִתְלוּ, וַעֲשָׂרָה מְחַזְּרִין עַל הַפְּתָחִים. קשה למה לא הרגו וכלו את אלו העשרה? ועוד למה היה להם עונש זה של עניות ולא עונש קשה יותר שיהיו מצורעים או סומין?
> ונראה דבלאו הכי יש להתפלאות למה הוצרך המן לספר לשר"ץ אשתו ואוהביו מספר בניו, וכי הם אינם יודעים כמה בנים יש לו? ונראה לי בס"ד כי המן היה מנאף עם נשי השרים בסתר והוליד ממזרים, ואלו העשרה היו ממזרים מנשים של השרים ולא היו מכירים בהם שר"ץ אשתו ואוהביו ולא שום אדם בעולם ואותה שעה גילה לאוהביו ולאשתו שכל כך הוא מוצלח בעניינו שהוליד עשרה בנים ממזרים מנשי השרים הגדולים ושום אדם לא ידע בו ועודם הם קיימים והם פלוני ופלוני והגיד להם שהוא מצליח ברע שיעשה, ולכך חושב שגם ברעה שיעשה למרדכי יצליח!
> ובזה מובן הטעם שהיו העשרה בנים אלה מחזירים על הפתחים, כי אלו העשרה היו חשובין בנים לבעלי אמותם שהיו שרים גדולים ועתה שגילה המן עליהם שהם בניו אז ידעו אותם השרים דאלו הם ממזרים ובני המן הם ואינם בניהם ואז גרשום מביתם ערומים והוכרחו להיות מחזירים על הפתחים כדי לאכול כי מי יפרנסם שנעשו עניים מרודים כי נתגרשו מביתם ערומים.
> ובזה יתורץ בס"ד דקדוק אחר דחד אמר שהיו שבעים וחד אמר שהיו ר"ח והנה בודאי כל אחד מן החכמים היתה קבלה בידו מרבותיו על דבר זה. וקשה איך יהיו חולקים במציאות? ובזה ניחא דעל בנים הגלויים הנולדים משר"ץ אשתו ליכא פלוגתא, וכל דברים אלו קאי על אותם בנים הממזרים שהיו להמן מנשי דעלמא אשר גילה אותם באותו היום לאוהביו ולשרץ אשתו, וחד אמר דאותם שנולדו מנשי שרים הגדולים היו עשרה ומחזרים על הפתחים, וחד אמר שהיו שבעים מאלו הממזרים מחזירים על הפתחים ושניהם נראה שהם מודים שהיה לו ר"ח בנים ממזרים שגילה אותם באותו היום אך חד סבירא ליה שעשרה מהם דוקא היו מחזרים על הפתחים וחד סבירא ליה שהיו שבעים מאלו הממזרים מחזרים על הפתחים.

In short: (My translation)

> Why were only ten killed? Why were the rest punished  with poverty?
> Another question is why did Haman have to tell them about his children; surely they were aware of his children?
> It appears that Haman fornicated with the wives of the ministers and had children in secret. He now revealed that he was so successful that he was able to have so many children by ministers' wives, and so he should also be successful against Mordechai!
> When it was discovered that these children were bastards, they were disowned and had to collect charity door to door.
> All opinions agree that Haman had 208 bastards, but they dispute how many ended up collecting charity.

Answer (score -2):

The gemara you cite would be considered aggadah.  There is an accepted tradition to not accept such statements as literal, especially if they contradict mikra. According to this school of thought, he did not have 208 children.  That same gemara also says he had 30, 70, 208 or 214 children. There is clearly something going on here nonliteral.  The Rambam would urge us to consider the possible reason for such numbers and what they might mean.

Taking aggadah literally causes all sorts of problems. The list of luminaries that don't take aggadah and midrash literally is endless.

Comment: `The Rambam would urge us to consider the possible reason for such numbers and what they might mean.` Sound more like Maharal.

Comment: "Sound more like Maharal" - Sorry I don't know how to properly quote.  This is what I'm referring to.  Rambam, intro to perek chelek:  ואם אתה מן הכת השלישית כשתראה דבר מדבריהם שהדעת מרחיק אותו תעמוד ותתבונן בו ודע שהוא חידה ומשל ותשכב עשוק הלב וטירוד הרעיון בחבורו ובסברתו ותחשוב למצא כוונת השכל ואמונת היושר כמו שנאמר למצוא דברי חפץ וכתוב יושר דברי אמת ואז תסתכל בספרי זה ויועיל לך בע"ה

Comment: I am familiar with that rambam, but the style of focusing on significance of numbers in an aggada is much more characteristic of maharal.

Comment: Why do you assume that it contradicts Mikrah? There is no verse which says that he _only_ had ten sons.

Comment: The question wasn't "how many sons did he have" it was "according to the position that he had 200 of them, why didn't they hang them?" You could think about it like this if you want "anyone speculating about additional sons, even as a parable, would be aware that 10 specific ones are named and killed. so how did they differentiate those 10 from the others?"

Comment: mevaqesh - I agree. Shmuel Brin - you are right, it doesn't contradict the posuk outright.  At least to me though, there still seems to be something else being hinted at in the gemara.  There are a lot of divergent opinions on how many sons he had.  Double AA - It turns out this question was a joke.  Honestly, I wouldn't have responded at all had it been tagged properly from the beginning.  I was only trying to offer one possible explanation as to why "all" his sons may not have been hanged.  It may be completely wrong.  It was just a proposal in line with the sentiments of the Rambam I quoted

Comment: Oy,  Now the purim-torah-in-jest tag has been removed.  I'm very confused.  it wasn't there at first.  Then it was.  Now it isn't again.  So this is a real question then?  Its not a silly question, I just at this point have no idea the intent of OP.

Comment: I think you used the word "literally" wrong